# Python win32com.client run can not find solver.xlam

Tags: python, vba, win32com

I was trying to use win32com.client to connect an Excel 2010 workbook and run its VBA macro. The macro uses the Excel solver.xlam. There is no problem running the Macro from Excel. But when using win32com.client to run the Macro, it terminated with error message saying the Macro cannot find solver.xlam. The file path shown in the dialog window is just my personal default folder, which is wrong. Anyone has a clue? Thanks!

Here is the code sample

```
import win32com.client

x1 = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
x1.Visible = False
x1.Workbooks.Open(Filename="Macro.xlsm")
x1.Application.Run("Macro.xlsm!Module1.Prediction")
x1.DisplayAlerts = False
x1.Application.Quit()
del x1
```

Comment: When having a problem with code it's best to post the code.  You should know however that when Excel is opened using automation, add-ins (such as e.g. Solver) do not load by default: you will need to load it using your code. See:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/213489

Comment: Thanks. According to your link, I tried to add x1.Workbooks.Open(Filename="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\Library\SOLVER\SOLVER.XLAM") to my code, and it works now.